# Using \path or \url within a foreach loop

Tags: foreach, url

When trying to nest `\url`  or `\path` within a for-each loop (not to be confused with TikZ paths), the text from the loop is not printed:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}

\begin{document}

\providecommand{\test}{}%
    \foreach \x in {%
        folder1/part_1,
        folder2/part_2%
    }{
   \gdef\test{\path{\x}}%
    \test}

\end{document}
```

Output:

`\x \x`

Desired Output:

`folder1/part_1` `folder2/part_2`

I have nested the output within a command for use elsewhere for another function (but the problem exists even without using commands).

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `\x` plus you need to expand `\x` inside `\path`

Comment: Apologies; a typo - fixed above and still has a problem. How would expand be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example that shows, how to expand the argument `\x` of `\path` (or `\url`).
The wrapper with macro `\test` is removed, it does not serve a purpose in the example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {%
    folder1/part_1,
    folder2/p a r t_2%
}{%
  \expandafter\path\expandafter{\x}
}

\end{document}
```